# Extract part of a string from each row of a column

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a column with rows that have a string. I only need a certain part of the string. All the rows have the part I need starting at the same character number but end at a different place so I could not use that logic to extract it.

For example, these are the cells from four of the rows in this column and I need the parts that say STRUCTURAL_PASSED for the first two and DW_MERGE_PROCESSING for the second two.

If I could extract that part of the string for each of those rows and make a new row with those extracts that would be ideal.

```
{"SEQUENCE_NUMBR":55641,"STATUS_OF_FILE_SYSTM":"STRUCTURAL_PASSED","REPORTING_SCHEDULE_NAME":"SPRING_2019"}

{"SEQUENCE_NUMBR":55641,"STATUS_OF_FILE_SYSTM":"STRUCTURAL_PASSED","REPORTING_SCHEDULE_NAME":"SPRING_2019"}

{"SEQUENCE_NUMBR":55641,"STATUS_OF_FILE_SYSTM"::"DW_MERGE_PROCESSING","REPORTING_SCHEDULE_NAME":"SPRING_2019"}

{"SEQUENCE_NUMBR":55641,"STATUS_OF_FILE_SYSTM":"DW_MERGE_PROCESSING","REPORTING_SCHEDULE_NAME":"SPRING_2019"}
```

Comment: Maybe a regex extraction? Maybe a JSON extraction/parsing could work too.

Answer (score 1):

You want the sub string starting from position 49 until the double quote excluding.

You can combine `SUBSTR` and `INSTR`:

```
substr(substr(text, 49, 4000), 1, instr(substr(text, 49, 4000), '"') - 1)
```

Or you can use `REGEXP_SUBSTR`:

```
regexp_substr(text, '[^"]+', 49)
```

Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=ac1a2e8bf3b7a55c6eeede6078e50bdd